# rails link_to_add_fields adds each field twice in nested form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms

I'm creating a nested form with three models.  The grants model and then two nested models: specs and subspecs.  Specs and subspecs both have the fields eligibility and ineligibility.  I believe I have the models and associations set up correctly but my issue comes in when I try to add new fields dynamically using jQuery.  Any field I add to eligibility also adds a blank field to ineligibility.  It doesn't show up on the form but when I look at the show page I see it.

eligibility

- A

ineligibility

- B

The result would be (x is blank):

eligibility

- A
- x

ineligibility

- x
- B

And when go back to the edit page there is now a blank field for each x.  I assume this is an error in my application helper and every time link_to_add_fields is used in one section of the form it triggers the creation of a field in another section.  Interestingly if I go back to edit and fill in the blank fields they will keep the new entries.  It just forces me to have an identical number of bullet points for each section which I don't want.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(name.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
```

and my form

```
<%= form_for(@grant) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :overview %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :overview %>
  </div>

<h2> Eligibility </h2>
  <%= f.fields_for :specs do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'eligibility_fields', f: builder %>
     <% end %>
     <%= link_to_add_fields "eligibility", f, :specs %>

<h2> Ineligibility </h2>
<%= f.fields_for :specs do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'ineligibility_fields', f: builder %>
     <% end %>
     <%= link_to_add_fields "ineligibility", f, :specs %>
```

and the eligibility_fields render

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.label :eligibility, "Eligibility" %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :eligibility %><br />
  <%= f.label :_destroy, "Remove Eligibility" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
  <%= f.fields_for :subspecs do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'subeligibility_fields', f: builder %>
    <% end %> 
  <%= link_to_add_fields "subeligibility", f, :subspecs %>
</fieldset>
```

and finally the jQuery

```
jQuery ->
  $('form').on 'click', '.remove_fields', (event) ->
    $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
    $(this).closest('fieldset').hide()
    event.preventDefault()

  $('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
    time = new Date().getTime()
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
    event.preventDefault()
```

I'm brand new to rails and especially jQuery so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: isn't that coffeescript?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the wrapper option worked for me:

```
= event.fields_for :photos, wrapper: false do |event|
```